# Same code base but different database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building an express app which handles multiple domains and clients. I am thinking to use same code base for multiple apps but with different database.

Is it possible connect to mongodb using promise. for example:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  var databaseName = util.sanitizeDBname(req.hostname);
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/'+databaseName, (err) => {
      if(err) reject(err);

      resolve(mongoose.connection);
    });
  });
  next();
});
```

Is it good? if no how to tackle "single code base with multiple DB" issue.

Thanks.